# Meteor countdown from server

Tags: meteor

I have a chat application and on the server I have a Meteor.setInterval that runs every 12 hours. Is there a simple way to somehow show a countdown clock on the client (I can't do it via time because it resets back too 12 hours every time the server restarts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would:

1. Create a date variable setting it to when the next interval is going to be run during each setInterval callback
2. Store it in a collection or variable.
3. Return it to the client on publish/on Meteor method call.
4. Do date math on the client along with a Meteor.setInterval to update your timer.

Comment: I made a simple tutorial question with the actual code

Comment: @NathanielDSouza where is the link to the tutorial? :)